# Remove only anchor tags from string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I know that to remove all html tags from a string one can use:

```
string = re.sub('<[^<]*?/?>', '', string)
```

But is there anyway that I can remove only anchor tags and keep all other tags. So for example:

```
<p>Some text<a href="#">link</a></p>
```

become:

```
<p>Some text link</p>
```

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/560648).

Comment: There's no reliable way to do that using regular expressions. Use an xml parser instead, such as beautifulsoup.

Comment: u can use it "(\b<.+>\w+<\/.*?>)(?=\<\/)" (remove quotes) => just for single line.

Comment: Toni, what are you trying to do, out of curiosity?  Even with native python there are better ways to parse html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's enough to look for opening and closing `a` tags separately and omit them:

```
<(?:a\b[^>]*>|/a>)
```

[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/MFH2yk/2)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks revo it worked perfectly. 
I also manage to fix this problem using this regex

```
string = re.sub('<a.*?>|</a> ', '', string)
```